# Verify the Rolle's theorem when $f(x)=(x+1)^m(x-1)^n,\;\;-1\leq x\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, continuity, rolles-theorem

Verify the Rolle's theorem when $f(x)=(x+1)^m(x-1)^n,\;\;-1\leq x\leq 1$ and show this result is not true for $f(x)=2x^{-2},\;\;\text{on}\;[-1,1]$ and $g(x)=|x|,\;\;\text{on}\;[-1,1].$

I know that the Rolle's Thoerem states that: Suppose

1. $f$ is continuous on $[\alpha,\beta];$
2. $f(\alpha)=f(\beta);$
3. $f'$ exists on $(\alpha,\beta).$

Then, $f$ has a local maximum or minimum at some $c\in (\alpha,\beta),$ thus $f'(c)=0.$

Please, can anyone help me out?

Comment: 1 is obvious as it is a polynomial.  2 is also because of the alternating signs of the bounds.  3 is obvious again as polynomials are differentiable.  Then take $f'(x)=0$ and solve, which gives you $c$.  Now apply that same logic on the second and third functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)=(x+1)^{m-1} (x-)^{n-1} (m(x-1)+n(x+1))$. Hence $f'(x)=0$ precisely when $x=\frac {m-n} {m+n}$. Note that this number is indeed in $[-1,1]$. If $n$ is even then $f$ is non-negative and 0 at the end points, so $f$ has  maximum at this point. If $n$ is odd then $f \leq 0$ and $f$ has  a minimum at this point.  For the the functions  $2x^{-2}$ and $|x|$ take $\alpha =-1, \beta =1$